# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: ViewProfile::$Profile_model

Tags: php, codeigniter

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suwAo.png)

The image above contains the error that occured while running the project.

As it was suggested, i tried including the following code:

> $autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);

but it did not yeild any result and infact it showed another error

> **An Error Was Encountered You have specified an invalid database connection group.**

Please, please give a solution.

[error that occured on applying the suggested code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc5VP.png)

Comment: You might have used `$this->db` on Login_model.php line 14. without initiating `$this->db`. You need to do something like `$this->db = new ModelClass();`. I dont know CodeIgniter but it should be the issue.

Comment: Try to use **$this->CI->db**

Comment: @AshishChoudhary.yes. tried that one too.it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add the constructor like

```
class Landing extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->database();
    }
}
```

and then in our model file try to execute query like

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('tablename');
$where = array('email' => $email);
$this->db->where($where);

$query = $this->db->get();
$resultId = $query->result_id;      
$row_count = $resultId->num_rows;
```

Hope so it will help you.

Comment: I had used the code as you have suggested.again got an error.I have uploaded the image in my question.**you have specified an invalid connection group**

Comment: check your database connnection and check your model extends ci_model